# Regex solution to remove balanced square brackets from a string from right to left iteratively in C++

Tags: c++, regex

Need a C++ regex solution to remove balanced []s from a string iteratively.
I have written the following code, but it does not cover the exact requirement.

```
std::string removeSqr(const std::string input)
{
    std::string result = input;
    while (true)
    {
        std::smatch match;
        if (std::regex_search(result, match, std::regex("\\[[^\\[\\]]*\\]$")))
        {
            result = match.prefix().str() + match.suffix().str();
            std::cout << result << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
             break;
        }
    }
    cout << "final : " << result << endl;
    return result;
}
```

This is working for the following example:

given => "abc[d]n[r][q]"
then => "abc[d]n[r]", "abc[d]n"

But it is not working for followings:

given => "abc[d]n[r][][5]"
should be => "abc[d]n[r][]", "abc[d]n[r]", "abc[d]n"

given => "abc[[]][]"
should be => "abc[[]]", "abc"

given => "abc[[s]5][w]"
should be => "abc[[s]5]", "abc"

.

Also, need a direct regex solution as well.

eg: "abc[[s]5][w]" -> "abc"

Comment: regexes and balanced/nested delimiters do not mix.

Comment: Regex alone can't handle nested braces because you need a stack for that and regex is a FA and hence is stackless.

Comment: IIRC a language with unbounded paired tokens (parenthesis, brackets, BEGIN/END tokens, etc) is never regular. Also, a regex solution is wildly inefficient. Just iterate over `input`, keeping a counter. Increment on `[`, decrement on `]`, copy input to output whenever `counter==0`. O(n) performance, O(1) storage for the counter,

Comment: @Evg: Regular Expressions are FAs; regex is not so constrained.

Comment: The regex provided does not handle nested square brackets.  Handling nested square brackets should be added in.  (Using a regex for this is really the wrong tool for the job, but if you have your heart set on regex it should be able to handle this problem.  Which may require advanced regex features, or if you have an arbitrary upper limit for how deeply the square brackets can nest.)

Comment: regex: https://xkcd.com/1171/

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, when providing a link to unrelated content you think is humorous please be more clear as to where the clicker is going, to avoid your comment being a time-waster (albeit, a small one) for readers only looking for serious suggestions.